# Disable parenthesis in ieee style biblatex

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber,sortcites]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
Refs. \cites{Yang10,Yang09}\\
\end{document}
```

The output is `[(1),(2)]`. How to remove parenthesis here? I see the output is [1, 2] in `numeric-comp` but I don't see in `ieee.cbx` where this parenthesis is added.

Comment: If you look in `ieee.cbx` you will see lots of `\bibopenbracket` etc. which are indeed adding brackets. Can you clarify what behaviour you actually want though ? You do not want brackets anywhere or just in multi-citations ? What about other types of referencing ?

Comment: @ach, I want `ieee` style. The output with multiple citation is `[(1),(2)]` but I want `[1,2]`. So parenthesis should be removed.

Comment: @rowman Is "[1, 2]" really the IEEE style? It looks like `ieee` is akin to `numeric-comp`, but all individuals labels are square-bracketed: "[1], [2]" and "[1]--[3]". To achieve this drop bracketing in the definition for `\cites` with: `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}{\cite}{\multicitedelim}`

Comment: @Audrey, maybe not completely IEEE style, but I need `[1,2]` or `[1-2]`. It's much more beautiful to my mind. That command gives `[1],[2]`. The reason that I am using IEEE is the style of printing the references at the end.

Comment: @rowman Then try loading biblatex with `citestyle=numeric-comp` and `bibstyle=ieee`. This question does raise a bug with `ieee` so you should get in touch with Joseph about that.

Comment: @Audrey, thanks for your answer. It works perfectly fine for me. What is the bug? I am using `lualatex`.

Comment: The IEEE style requires brackets around each number: certainly with `\cite` this works fine (in the latest version). There are some issues with the way `biblatex` details with bracketing, at least for me in this style, so I'm not 100% sure whether `\cites` is workable.

Comment: @JosephWright For `\cites` `numeric-comp` uses `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\mkbibbrackets]{\cite}{\multicitedelim}`. Since your `\cite` command applies all the individual brackets, I think you just need to omit the wrapper argument `\mkbibbrackets`.

Comment: Should be fixed in v1.1i, uploaded to CTAN just now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through the comments I understood that I had to use `citestyle=numeric-comp` and `bibstyle=ieee` to achieve the desired output.
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric-comp,bibstyle=ieee,%
backend=biber,sortcites]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{} % Remove annoying dash
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
Refs. \cite{Yang10,Yang09}\\
\end{document}
```

`ref.bib` should be available. I am using `lualatex`.