# Multiple citations as [1,2] with single \cite

Tags: biblatex, citing

At the moment I have something like this in my latex document: `\cite{NgRussell:ICML2000,AbbeelNg:ICML2004}`

However in the pdf this appears as [3], [5] while I would like to see [3,5].

The following lines in my preamble could be affecting this, but I have no idea which ones:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,sorting=none,urldate=comp,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    urlseen = {Retrieved},
}
```

Comment: Setting `style=numeric-comp` in the options of `biblatex` should provide this. If not, please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118991/disable-parenthesis-in-ieee-style-biblatex